# Creating vector of datetimes for Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas

I have two dataframes `df_trade` and `df_close`, and I want to store their dot product in `ts_fund`, but it doesn't matter if `ts_fund` is an array, dataframe, vector, etc. Those two dataframes store values and time as `datetime`. For example, `df_trade`:

```
2011-1-05 15 100
2011-1-20 10 200
```

and `df_close`

```
2011-1-05 1 .5
2011-1-20 .8 .1
```

So I want the result in `ts_fund` to be:

```
2011-1-05 65
2011-1-20 28
```

I tried the below

```
ts_fund = np.zeros((len(ldt_timestamps), 1))
ts_fund = pd.DataFrame(ts_fund, index=ldt_timestamps, columns='portfolio value')

 for index, row in df_trade.iterrows():
    portfolio_value = np.dot(row.values.astype(float), df_close.ix[index].values)
    ts_fund[index] = portfolio_value
```

But I got the error

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'portfolio value' was passed
```

Would it be easier if I set `ts_fund` as a vector or array instead of a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Does this suffice?

```
def equity(df1,df2):
    shape1 = df1.shape
    shape2 = df2.shape
    if not shape1 == shape2:
        raise Exception("df's are of different size!")
    return df1.mul(df2, axis='columns', fill_value=0).sum(axis =1)

equity(df1, df2)  

2011-01-05    65
2011-01-20    28
dtype: float64
```

In general, avoid iterating over rows unless it's absolutely necessary and try to harness pandas' vectorized operations